# curl command line POST array of objects

Tags: curl

I am looking for curl command to post an array of objects.

here is my payload

```
[
 {
   'name': 'Alice',
   'age': 15
 },
 {
   'name': 'Bob',
   'age': 20
 },
 ...
]
```

I have tried multiple ways but unable to post data. might be I am doing something wrong with command.

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/en/api/v2/users/30/employees' 
-X POST -d @employees.json -H 'authorization: Basic ZGFudWJlOkRhbnU4ZQ=='
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ReactNativeDebugger/0.9.7 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Electron/1.7.15 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
-H 'X-DevTools-Request-Id: 17620.46' --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending invalid Json in your payload. This is why you are getting error. please change your payload like following

```
[
 {
   "name": "Alice",
   "age": 15
 },
 {
   "name": "Bob",
   "age": 20
 }
]
```

It will work. You can use JSLinter to evaluate your json. Also it is good practice to add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to tell that you are sending JSON data.